# pgsql function with postgis function to return all points from polygon within radius and point

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, postgis

i have a table with those columns job_name, layer_name, polygon which is public.geometry and has many points in it. i want to create a function that gets 2 arguments: point and radius and will return for each job+layer all the points that all the polygon's points exists in the distance from the given point ordered by the distance . do it using postgresql with postgis functions. polygon has many points in it and for each layer+job i want all the points from all the polygons so it need to iterate through all the polygon from the same layer and job . return this as json like this

```
{
   "job":"<JOB NAME>",
   "layer":"<LAYER NAME>",
   "defects":[
      {
         "items":[
            {
               polygon_point_1,
               "distance":<DISTANCE1>
            },
            {
               polygon_point_2,
               "distance":<DISTANCE2>
            },
            "…"
         ]
      },
      "..."
```

my code so far is like this:

```
SELECT
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'job', job_name,
        'layer', layer_name,
        'defects', JSON_AGG(
            JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                'items', JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                    'polygon_point', polygon_point,
                    'distance', ST_Distance(polygon_point, ST_GeomFromText(polygon_point, 4326))
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS result
FROM (
    SELECT
        job_name,
        layer_name,
        (ST_DumpPoints(polygon)).geom as polygon_point
    FROM cam_data_step_items
    WHERE ST_DWithin(polygon, ST_GeomFromText(polygon_point, 4326), radius)
) t
GROUP BY job_name, layer_name
```

error im getting when running the following:

```
SELECT get_polygons_by_distance('POINT(1 1)', 1);
```

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
  Hint: "01" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
  Where: parallel worker
SQL function "get_polygons_by_distance" statement 1
```

can someone help please?

Comment: There are many things wrong in this query. You can start with simple queries and once you have them working, then assemble them into a more complex one. For the specific error you are mentioning (but you will get more errors), `st_dump().geom` is a geometry, so you can't (and don't need to) apply `ST_GeomFromText` on it, you can use the geometry directly (`polygon_point`)

Comment: Hi! It's always best to post a minimal reproducible example instead of a long query that can only be debugged in our heads. Consider adding 1) create table statements 2) insert statements 3) sample data and 4) the exact expected results. Preferably in a fiddle of your choice, e.g. [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30)